# Why did Louka despise Raina from the very beginning of Shaws Arms and the Man?

Tags: character-analysis, george-bernard-shaw, arms-and-the-man

In Shaw's play *Arms and the Man*, Louka, Raina’s maid, had somewhat bitter feelings for her mistress Raina. Why? From the first Act the dialogues of Louka do show her resentment (although it is subtle) for her. It’s my personal observation that in the whole play Raina never treated Louka badly unless she started it.

I want to know the psychological reason of the hatred of Louka for Raina.